# Correctly calculating point on a bicubic Bézier surface

Tags: javascript, math

I wrote a function that should return a point on a bicubic [Bézier surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_surface) from a 4x4 matrix of control points for parameters u and v, which are element of [0, 1], using [Bernstein polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial). But either my function doesn't work like it should, or my understanding of the matter is even worse than I thought.

The function to calculate the point looks like this:

```
var bezierSurface = function (u, v, p) {
  var result = [];

  var p00 = p[0],  p01 = p[1],  p02 = p[2],  p03 = p[3],
      p10 = p[4],  p11 = p[5],  p12 = p[6],  p13 = p[7],
      p20 = p[8],  p21 = p[9],  p22 = p[10], p23 = p[11],
      p30 = p[12], p31 = p[13], p32 = p[14], p33 = p[15];

  var uin = (1 - u),
      vin = (1 - v);

  var bu0 = Math.pow(uin, 3),
      bu1 = 3 * u * Math.pow(uin, 2),
      bu2 = 3 * Math.pow(u, 2) * uin,
      bu3 = Math.pow(u, 3);

  var bv0 = Math.pow(vin, 3),
      bv1 = 3 * v * Math.pow(vin, 2),
      bv2 = 3 * Math.pow(v, 2) * vin,
      bv3 = Math.pow(v, 3);

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    result.push(
      p00[i] * bu0 * bv0 +
      p01[i] * bu0 * bv1 +
      p02[i] * bu0 * bv2 +
      p03[i] * bu0 * bv3 +

      p10[i] * bu1 * bv0 +
      p11[i] * bu1 * bv1 +
      p12[i] * bu1 * bv2 +
      p13[i] * bu1 * bv3 +

      p20[i] * bu2 * bv0 +
      p21[i] * bu2 * bv1 +
      p22[i] * bu2 * bv2 +
      p23[i] * bu2 * bv3 +

      p30[i] * bu3 * bv0 +
      p31[i] * bu3 * bv1 +
      p32[i] * bu3 * bv2 +
      p33[i] * bu3 * bv3
    );
  }

  return result;
};
```

Most probably this is not the most efficient way to get the job done, but since I'm just getting started with parametric surfaces, I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible, yet not even thinking about tesselating the surface to get vertices for triangles or something like that.

Now, the **problem** appeared when I called the function with the following arguments:

```
var getSurfacePoint = function () {
  var u = 0.5,
      v = 0.25;

  var cp = [
    [-1.0, 0.0, -1.0],
    [-0.5, 0.3, -0.8],
    [ 0.5, 0.3, -0.8],
    [ 1.0, 0.0, -1.0],

    [-0.8, 0.3, -0.5],
    [-0.3, 1.0, -0.4],
    [ 0.3, 1.0, -0.4],
    [ 0.8, 0.3, -0.5],

    [-0.8, 0.3,  0.5],
    [-0.3, 1.0,  0.4],
    [ 0.3, 1.0,  0.4],
    [ 0.8, 0.3,  0.5],

    [-1.0, 0.0,  1.0],
    [-0.5, 0.3,  0.8],
    [ 0.5, 0.3,  0.8],
    [ 1.0, 0.0,  1.0]
  ];

  return bezierSurface(u, v, cp);
};
```

The result of calling `bezierSurface` via `getSurfacePoint` is `-0.4437500000000001` for **x**, `0.5625` for **y** and `-4.683753385137379e-17` for **z**, and that is *not* what I expected. I mean, at first sight, the return values for x and y seem plausible, but considering the values provided by the matrix of control points, the return value for z just looks completely wrong.

As far as I understand it, the points of a Bézier curve as well as the points of a Bézier surface are always enclosed within the convex hull of the control polygon, that is here represented by the points of the 4x4 matrix. So, when the range of z-values of the control points only goes from `-1.0` to `1.0`, how can the calculated point of the surface have a z-value `< -4.0`?

If we suppose the result **is** wrong, there must be something wrong with my function to calculate the point on the surface, but though alternately staring at `bezierSurface` and the mathematical definition of the Bézier surface for some time, I wasn't able to spot the error yet. I hope someone else can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > the return value for z just looks completely wrong

-4.683753385137379**e-17**, the value is (almost) 0. The result looks pretty right.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your answer! I thought **e-17** was just some kind of abbreviation for more numbers behind the point and nothing that would change the meaning of the whole expression. My browser should not expect me to know this. :-P

Comment: this is called Scientific-notation and is nothing browser-specific.